# How can I force reload the parent component from action of child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, refresh

Please check the link I provide, I want to refresh the table when an item is added to the table via API, and refresh the table when an item is removed.

The button to add data into table is in child element, but the table that showing data is in parent component, so I'm not sure how can I click the button that is in child to force parent to reload/refresh

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-monad-lf402?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue (to add an item, must tick the radio button in my UI first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $emit to send a notification to your parent element.

So when confirmed you can send the $emit

```
this.$emit('weAreSure')
```

And in the parent component html:

```
<HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" @weAreSure="handleweAreSure"/>
```

And the handleweAreSure is just a vue method where you can reload your data,
Or alternatively you can add some parameters to the method.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-beaver-bgm1b

For more information about emit https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

If you have to use a lot of $emits within you application maybe it is worth to look at vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to force reload your table, Vue is reactive, meaning that when you update the model, the view updates automatically.

> One of Vue’s most distinct features is the unobtrusive reactivity system. Models are just plain JavaScript objects. When you modify them, the view updates. It makes state management simple and intuitive, but it’s also important to understand how it works to avoid some common gotchas.

[Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

For example, if you want the table to update when you delete a trend, you should remove the trend from the model, you're currently just sending an api request.

You can put `this.toptrackTrends = this.toptrackTrends.filter(x => x.ID !== deleteid);` at the bottom of your `DeleteTrend` method, this will filter out any trends that have an ID of deleteid.

Comment: So this method deletes the element that already exist in (toptrackTrends). How about when I add new item to it? Because the only way that (toptrackTrends) can get new item is to recall the API again am I right?

Comment: With your current setup, you could do something like @dreijntjens suggests and subscribe to an event like `<HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" @addTrend="toptrackTrends.push($event)" />` and then emit the event when you add a trend `this.$emit("addTrend", newtrend);`